# How to set up Flex with Oracle 10g?

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, oracle10g, flex4, database-connection

I am new to Flex 3/4 and wish to discover what is involved in creating an application in Flex that runs off an Oracle 10g database to both retrieve/modify data from, with Flex.

Basically I would like to know how to connect Flex to an Oracle database to perform database transactions like updates/deletes/inserts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adobe Flex 3 Help - [About data access](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=data_intro_2.html):

> The Flex SDK contains features for
>   accessing server-side data. Flex data
>   access components are based on a
>   service-oriented architecture (SOA).
>   These components use remote procedure
>   calls to interact with server
>   environments, such as PHP, Adobe
>   ColdFusion, and Microsoft ASP.NET, to
>   provide data to Flex applications and
>   send data to back-end data sources.

Personally I prefer Java with the **BlazeDS/Spring/Hibernate** stack. For tutorials look at the Adobe Developer Connection:

- [Adobe Flex, BlazeDS, and Hibernate JPA on Tomcat and MySQL](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/flex_hibernate.html)
- [The Flex, Spring, and BlazeDS full stack](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/fullstack_pt1.html)

Answer (score 0):

I use GraniteDS which is a bit complicated and takes time to learn, if you want something more simple then use Adobes BlazeDS, and more simple still use PHP ( http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/flex_php.html).